# React state value is wrong in functional component when read from event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I am trying to convert a fairly simple React class component to functional component. Here on document click I want to toggle the `isShown` boolean value between `true` and `false`. But each time `onClick` is fired, the value `isShown` is always `false`, even though it was previously toggled to `true`. I do not understand what is going on here and how to fix it?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Popover({}: any) {

    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        document!.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    }, []);

    function onClick(e: Event) {
        console.log(isShown);
        setIsShown(!isShown);
    }

    return (<div></div>);
}
```

Comment: use https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback and add isShown to the dependency list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on the `useEffect`. In there you added a listener that the callback function is `onClick`. The `onClick` function is declared with `isShown: false` at the first. So the `onClick` will be something like that:

```js
    function onClick(e: Event) {
        console.log(false); // isShown is `false` and will be logged
        setIsShown(!false); // isShown will be set to `true`
    }
```

So when you click on the button, the `isShown` value will be changed to `true` but the `onClick` function won't be declared again for the listener in the useEffect and the callback function of the event listener is the one I explained before. Now, you know the problem and you have two solutions:

1. Changing the `onClick` funtion to not to depend on the `isShown` state like this:

```js
    function onClick(e: Event) {
        setIsShown(previousValue => !previousValue);
    }
```

2. Changing the useEffect to be sensetive to the `onClick` changes. For this solution, to avoid the infinit rerenders, you need to memoize the `onClick` function or move the function in the body of the useEffect:

```js
    const onClick = useCallback((e: Event) => {
        console.log(isShown);
        setIsShown(!isShown);
    }, [isShown]);

    useEffect(() => {
        document!.addEventListener('click', onClick);
        return () => document!.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    }, [onClick]);
```

OR

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        function onClick(e: Event) {
            console.log(isShown);
            setIsShown(!isShown);
        }
        document!.addEventListener('click', onClick);
        return () => document!.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    }, [isShown]);
```

Comment: Very well explained, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the event listener is necessary. Why don't you add an `onClick` attribute to the element that needs to change `isShown`? If it is the `div` then perhaps do something like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Popover({}: any) {

    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

    function handleClick() {
        console.log(isShown);
        setIsShown(!isShown);
    }

    return (<div onClick={()=> handleClick()}></div>);
}
```